# HTMLUnit won't execute JavaScript and load all content while CSS is disabled

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have been trying to use HTMLUnit to scrape page data from a miner address dashboard on ethermine.org. An example URL would be:

`https://ethermine.org/miners/32885f190a878d6db68cbC2889a3FF3abE3C257C/dashboard`

Calling `webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);` stops the javascript from loading the table data. The docs for this method are:

> Enables/disables CSS support. By default, this property is enabled. If disabled HtmlUnit will not download the linked css files and also not triggered the associated onload/onerror events.

So, I assume what's happening is Javascript is only executed when the CSS is successfully loaded. Enabling CSS makes loading the page far too long for my use case. So, I'm asking if there is a way to enable the Javascript to run to load the table data from this page, while keeping CSS disabled. Perhaps this can be done by triggering the onload events? How can this be done. Thanks

Here is the code and log output:

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false); // comment this line out and the active worker table data loads just fine
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

        try {

            WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("https://ethermine.org/miners/32885f190a878d6db68cbC2889a3FF3abE3C257C/dashboard"));
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);

            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000); // long enough for all javascript to execute

            System.out.println(page.asText());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output with CSS disabled:

```
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:09 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole error
SEVERE: TypeError: Cannot find function get in object .
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:09 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole error
SEVERE: TypeError: Cannot find function isEqualNode in object [object HTMLLinkElement].
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:10 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://ethermine.org/css/chunk-vendors.391ed6f9.css
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:10 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://ethermine.org/css/app.69e6b25a.css
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:10 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://ethermine.org/css/Dashboard.eb03c99b.css
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-color" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-color" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-color" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-color" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:17:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-opacity" is undefined
Home - Ethermine - Ethereum (ETH) mining pool
ETH
ETH
ZEC
YEC
ETC
BEAM
RVN
unchecked
Home
Statistics
Luck
Support
Start Mining
News
News
Legal Notices
ImprintPrivacy PolicyTerms of Operation
Resources
Help Desk3rd Party AppsAPI
Pools
ethermine.orgetc.ethermine.orgzcash.flypool.orgycash.flypool.orgbeam.flypool.orgravencoin.flypool.org
Other Platforms
etherchain.orgpoolwatch.iozcha.inyec.zcha.inbeaconcha.in
```

Here is the log output with CSS enabled:

```
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:02 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole error
SEVERE: TypeError: Cannot find function get in object .
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:02 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole error
SEVERE: TypeError: Cannot find function isEqualNode in object [object HTMLLinkElement].
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:03 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://api.ethermine.org/miner/32885f190a878d6db68cbC2889a3FF3abE3C257C/dashboard
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:03 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://api.ethermine.org/miner/32885f190a878d6db68cbC2889a3FF3abE3C257C/dashboard/payouts
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:03 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://api.ethermine.org/poolStats
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:03 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://api.ethermine.org/miner/32885f190a878d6db68cbC2889a3FF3abE3C257C/settings
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:03 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://api.ethermine.org/miner/32885f190a878d6db68cbC2889a3FF3abE3C257C/dashboard/msg
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:07 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://ethermine.org/css/chunk-vendors.391ed6f9.css
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:07 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://ethermine.org/css/app.69e6b25a.css
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:07 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to https://ethermine.org/css/Dashboard.eb03c99b.css
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-color" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-color" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-color" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-color" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-secondary-opacity" is undefined
Feb 08, 2021 5:18:08 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole warn
WARNING: cssVars(): variable "--fa-primary-opacity" is undefined
Home - Ethermine - Ethereum (ETH) mining pool
ETH
ZEC
YEC
ETC
BEAM
RVN
unchecked
Home
Statistics
Luck
Support
Start Mining
News
0x32885f190a878d6db68cbC2889a3FF3abE3C257C
Dashboard
Payouts
Settings
Help Desk
Auto-Updateunchecked
Workers Active / Inactive
0/0
Unpaid Balance
0.00012 ETH
Estimated Earnings
0.00016 ETH
Daily
Hashrate
Current (GH/s)
0.0
Average (GH/s)
0.0
Reported (GH/s)
0.0
Shares
Valid 99%
0
Stale 1%
0
Invalid
0
Created with Highcharts 7.1.2HashrateHashrateCurrent HashrateAverage HashrateReported Hashrate18:0020:0022:008. Feb02:0004:0006:0008:0010:0012:0014:0016:0010.0 GH/s10.2 GH/s10.4 GH/s10.6 GH/s10.8 GH/s
Created with Highcharts 7.1.2SharesWorkersShares & WorkersValid SharesWorkersStale Shares2021
Active Workers (57)
Name    Reported Hashrate   Current Hashrate    Valid Shares    Stale Shares    Invalid Shares  Last seen
1-1 183.7   188.8   168 3   0   8 minutes ago
1-2 183.8   188.8   168 3   0   9 minutes ago
1-3 183.8   161.8   145 1   0   8 minutes ago
1-4 183.8   179.9   160 3   0   8 minutes ago
10-1    192.2   182.2   162 3   0   9 minutes ago
10-2    194.5   192.9   173 1   0   8 minutes ago
10-3    192.3   196.3   176 1   0   8 minutes ago
10-4    189.3   209.2   185 5   0   9 minutes ago
11-1    192.0   179.2   158 5   0   9 minutes ago
11-2    168.9   149.9   133 3   0   8 minutes ago
11-3    194.8   177.7   158 3   0   8 minutes ago
11-4    198.6   163.7   146 2   0   9 minutes ago
12-1    190.9   207.8   187 0   0   9 minutes ago
12-2    163.9   169.9   151 3   0   8 minutes ago
12-3    170.1   188.5   169 1   0   9 minutes ago
12-4    170.2   145.9   130 2   0   8 minutes ago
13-1    167.9   182.2   162 3   0   8 minutes ago
13-2    182.4   157.4   141 1   0   8 minutes ago
13-3    186.4   187.0   167 2   0   8 minutes ago
13-4    166.2   156.3   140 1   0   9 minutes ago
14-1    202.2   185.8   164 5   0   8 minutes ago
14-2    269.4   283.3   253 3   0   8 minutes ago
15-1    265.2   245.7   214 11  0   8 minutes ago
15-2    167.8   186.7   168 0   0   8 minutes ago
15-3    161.3   154.4   139 0   0   8 minutes ago
2-1 181.5   164.4   146 3   0   8 minutes ago
2-2 174.7   181.4   162 2   0   8 minutes ago
2-3 188.3   188.4   167 4   0   8 minutes ago
2-4 188.3   198.1   175 5   0   8 minutes ago
3-1 192.6   170.3   152 2   0   8 minutes ago
3-2 183.7   179.6   161 1   0   9 minutes ago
3-3 188.3   189.6   170 1   0   8 minutes ago
3-4 164.4   162.5   143 5   0   9 minutes ago
4-1 168.4   150.0   135 0   0   8 minutes ago
4-2 192.7   191.1   172 0   0   8 minutes ago
4-3 192.5   211.1   190 0   0   8 minutes ago
4-4 192.4   182.9   164 1   0   8 minutes ago
5-1 168.4   176.6   157 3   0   9 minutes ago
5-2 192.5   210.3   188 2   0   9 minutes ago
5-3 171.3   183.2   161 6   0   8 minutes ago
5-4 193.5   178.5   160 1   0   8 minutes ago
6-1 140.4   145.2   130 1   0   8 minutes ago
6-2 190.9   181.1   163 0   0   8 minutes ago
6-3 191.6   206.7   186 0   0   8 minutes ago
6-4 190.4   185.1   164 4   0   8 minutes ago
7-1 194.5   186.3   167 1   0   8 minutes ago
7-2 193.2   179.2   160 2   0   8 minutes ago
7-3 197.2   208.1   186 2   0   8 minutes ago
7-4 194.7   187.0   167 2   0   8 minutes ago
8-1 193.1   188.5   169 1   0   8 minutes ago
8-2 192.3   187.0   167 2   0   8 minutes ago
8-3 146.0   145.4   127 6   0   8 minutes ago
8-4 196.4   218.1   195 2   0   8 minutes ago
9-1 194.6   207.8   187 0   0   8 minutes ago
9-2 191.7   167.8   151 0   0   10 minutes ago
9-3 152.4   151.4   135 2   0   9 minutes ago
9-4 194.2   207.7   185 3   0   9 minutes ago
Legal Notices
ImprintPrivacy PolicyTerms of Operation
Resources
Help Desk3rd Party AppsAPI
Pools
ethermine.orgetc.ethermine.orgzcash.flypool.orgycash.flypool.orgbeam.flypool.orgravencoin.flypool.org
Other Platforms
etherchain.orgpoolwatch.iozcha.inyec.zcha.inbeaconcha.in
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, I assume what's happening is Javascript is only executed when the CSS is successfully loaded.

That's wrong - there is no such dependency.

Maybe the js code stops because it relays on the existence of some css stuff. Check your log and please try to add

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

to not stop js execution at the first error.
If this does not help please open an issue on GitHub.